# C++ Vector understanding

Tags: vector, c++14

I am currently using codewars.com to practice my coding skills. I finished one of the problems and wanted to check what other people's solutions were and I found one I couldn't understand. It's much better than my solution and I would like to understand it more. such what does "*std" do exactly. what is the +=i doing to the min_elements and what is happening to the min elements?

```
long queueTime(std::vector<int> customers,int n){

std::vector<long> queues(n, 0);

  for (int i : customers)
    *std::min_element(queues.begin(), queues.end()) += i;

  return *std::max_element(queues.cbegin(), queues.cend());
}
```

This was my solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <array>
using namespace std;
long queueTime(std::vector<int> customers,int n){

int i = 0;                        //start of Queue
int count = 0;                    //keeps track of how many items has been         
processed
int biggest = 0;                  //Last/largest ending item size, add to count at end

int list [n];                     //Declared number of registers by size n
for(int k = 0;k<n;k++)            //sets each existing register to have 0 
items
{
  list[k] = 0;
}
//Start of processing customers, ends when last customer is at register.
for (auto i = customers.begin(); i!=customers.end();)
{
//checks if there are free registers.
for(int index = 0; index<n && i!=customers.end();index++)
  {
if(list[index]==0)
{
  list[index] = *i;
  i++;
}
  }
//Subtract 1 from every register
int temp=0;
for (int k =0;k<n;k++)
{
  if(list[k]!= 0)
  {
    temp = list[k];
    temp = temp-1;
    list[k] = temp;
  }
}
//increase count of items processed
count++;
}
//calculates the largest number of items a customer has amungst the last few 
customers.
for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
{
  if(list[j]>biggest)
  {
    biggest = list[j];
  }
}
//end first part
cout<<"\nCount: "<<count<<" Biggest: "<<biggest<<endl;
cout<<"End Function:" 

<<"\n************************\n*************************** 
*******************\n"<<endl;
//answer if number of items processed + last biggest number of items.
  return count+biggest;

}
```

Comment: This was my solution:

Comment: `std` is a namespace. `vector<T>` is part of that namespace, hence the reference ( std:: ). += is just shorthand. `x = x + 1` is the same as `x += 1`.

Answer (score 0):

The code is mapping a set of integers to `n` buckets and minimizing the sum of the elements assigned to a given bucket.

For each customer `int i` , the smallest element of the queue is incremented by `i`. Then the largest resulting queue value is returned.

[`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) is a [qualified name lookup](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lookup) of an identifier within the `std` namespace.

[`min_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min_element) returns an [iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/ForwardIterator). The dereference operator (`*`) produces an `lvalue` that is incremented by a [compound assignment operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_assignment) (`+=`).

Comment: What does minimizing the sum mean?